# jqGrid - Getting unformatted rowData from parent grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have following jqGrid and child grid using `subgrid`. In the `subGridRowExpanded` event I am trying to alert parent row’s column value as shown below – but it is displaying `formatted` value only.

What is the best jqGrid approach to get the column value from the selected parent row inside the showChildGrids function?

```
    function showChildGrids(parentRowID, parentRowKey) 
    {
        alert(parentRowKey);
        var rowData = $(mainGrid).jqGrid('getRowData', parentRowKey)
        //var rowData = $(mainGrid).getRowData(parentRowID);

        alert(rowData.RoutingID);
    }

    function createRoutingGrid()
    {

            $(mainGrid).jqGrid({
                url: "invNewWORouting.aspx/GetRoutings",
                mtype: 'POST',
                datatype: "local", //json if want to load initially
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                postData:
                {
                    workOrder: function () 
                    {
                        //var selectedWorkOrder = $( "select[class='workOrderDropdown']" ).val();
                        //return selectedWorkOrder;
                        return "5454430506";
                    }
                },

                serializeGridData: jqGridCustomSerializer,
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function (obj) { return obj.d; }
                },
                colNames: ['Routing ID', 'Destinations'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'RoutingID', index: 'RoutingID', formatter:mySpacePreserveFormatter, width:150 },
                    { name: 'Destinations', index: 'Destinations', width:400 }
                ],
                multiselect:true,
                multiboxonly:false,
                rowNum: 10,
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                height: "auto",
                loadonce: true,
                subGrid: true, // set the subGrid property to true to show expand buttons for each row
                subGridRowExpanded: showChildGrids, // javascript function that will take care of showing the child grid
                subGridOptions: { "plusicon" : "ui-icon-plus",
                                  "minusicon" :"ui-icon-minus",
                                  "openicon" : "",
                                  "reloadOnExpand" : false,
                                  "selectOnExpand" : false },
                beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) 
                {
                    //Reset all checkboxes before selection
                    $(this).jqGrid('resetSelection');

                    var $self = $(this);
                    var $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td");
                    var rowid = $td.parent().attr("id");
                    var rowData = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);

                    //Set variable for RoutingID
                    userSelectedRoutingID = rowData.RoutingID;

                    //Allow row selection
                    return true; 
                }
            });

            //Hide header checkbox
            $("#cb_"+mainGrid[0].id).hide();
        }
```

**Formatter**

```
        function mySpacePreserveFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
        {
         return '<pre>' + cellvalue + '</pre>';
        }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: `getRowData` works differently in different version of jqGrid and in different forks of jqGrid. So it's very important to know which one you use. The test input data are required too. Which rowid you specify in input data? Which meaning have the `mySpacePreserveFormatter` at all? Do yo use HTML fragments as input data for the main grid and subgrid or not (you don't use `autoencode: true` option). Could you provide the demo which reproduce the problem? You use `datatype: "local"` without `data` and with many other options which will be ignored with `datatype: "local"`, so your code is unclear.

Comment: By the way, it's bad to use `formatter` without specifying the corresponding unformatter (see `unformat` in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting))

Comment: @Oleg I am using `jqGrid  4.6.0`. The `mySpacePreserveFormatter` code is present in the question. I use datatype `local` initially and when I need to bind the data I make it as `json`. I don't have a demo as of now since it is using data from server.

Comment: Look at the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/x0xm6zbs/2/ as an example how you can create the demo which use `datatype: "json"`. The callback `showChildGrids` don't shows where you get the data for the subgrid and how you try to create it. I wrote you before that I don't see any need to use `mySpacePreserveFormatter` in jqGrid 4.6 because the CSS rule `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { white-space: pre; }` should be applied by default. In any way if you do need to use formatter you should always define unformatter too. The most unclear for me is the question: where you return the data for subgrid?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a hidden column in colModel that contains the non formatted routing id :

```
  colNames: ['Routing ID', 'Destinations', 'nonFormattedRoutingID'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'RoutingID', index: 'RoutingID',       formatter:mySpacePreserveFormatter, width:150 },
                    { name: 'Destinations', index: 'Destinations', width:400 },
  {name: 'nonFormattedRoutingID', index: 'nonFormattedRoutingID', hidden:true}
                ],
```

Then get the value of the column in function `showChildGrids`